# Using multiple cores to process large, sequential file in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, multicore, tbb

I have a large file (bigger then RAM, can't read whole at once) and i need to process it row by row (in c++). I want to utilize multiple cores, preferably with Intel **TBB** or Microsoft **PPL**. I would rather avoid preprocessing this file (like splitting it to 4 parts etc).

I was thinking about something like using 4 iterators, initialized to (0, n/4, 2*n/4 3*n/4) positions in the file etc.

Is it good solution and is there **simple** way to achieve it?

Or maybe you know some libs that supports efficient, concurrent reading of streams?

**update**:

I did tests. IO is not the bottleneck, CPU is. And I have lot of RAM for buffers.

I need to parse record (var size, approx. 2000 bytes each, records are separated by unique '\0' char), validate it, do some calculations, and write result to another file(s)

Comment: What kind of processing are you doing?

Comment: I see a problem with this: every set of reads from `(0, n/4, 2*n/4, 3*n/4) + i` will include at least four disk seeks, and I/O might become the bottleneck.

Comment: @sehe: You have a point, I was assuming too much.

Comment: @sehe: given that the file is "bigger than RAM", I think we can safely assume it's not on a RAM disk.

Comment: @Space's question is very relevant, do you know whether it's the IO that's killing you or your processing? You could look at a memory mapped implementation (i.e. map a block, process, then move to the next block etc.) This *may* help you reduce IO...

Comment: I did tests. IO is not the bottleneck, CPU is. And I have lot of RAM for buffers. I need to parse record (var size, approx. 2000 bytes each, records are separated by unique  '\0' ), validate it, do some calculations, and write result to another file(s).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you are able to split it into `N` parts, it sounds like the processing of each row is largely independent.  In that case, I think the simplest solution is to set up one thread to read the file line by line and place each row into a `tbb::concurrent_queue`.  Then spawn as many threads as you need to pull rows off that queue and process them.

This solution is independent of the file size, and if you find you need more (or less) worker threads its trivial to change the number.  But this won't work if there's some kind of dependencies between the rows... unless you set up a second poll of "post processing" threads to handle that, but then things may start to get too complex.

Comment: How about the write-out? I was doing a similar task and used the exact approach in reading and processing. But it seems outputting files could be a bottleneck from multiple threads. Currently, I am using mutex lock in C to write to the same output file. Any suggestion?

Comment: If each piece of data is independent and you know where it goes without having to look at data before then you can write to the same file from multiple threads using pwrite to have each thread write the data in the correct place.

Answer (score 6):

My recommendation is to use TBB's pipeline pattern. The first, serial stage of the pipeline reads a desired portion of data from file; subsequent stages process data chunks in parallel, and the last stage writes into another file, possibly in the same order as the data were read.

An example for this approach is available in TBB distributions; see examples/pipeline/square. It uses "old" interface, the class `tbb::pipeline` and filters (classes inherited from `tbb::filter`) that pass data by `void*` pointers. A newer, type-safe and lambda-friendly "declarative" interface `tbb::parallel_pipeline()` may be more convenient to use.

Answer (score 3):

ianmac already hinted at the seek issue. Your iterator idea is reasonable with a slight twist: initialize them to 0,1,2 and 3, and increment each by 4. So, the first thread works on items 0,4,8, etc. The OS will make sure the file is being fed to your app as quickly as possible. It may be possible to tell your OS that you'll be doing a sequential scan through the file (e.g. on Windows, it's a flag to `CreateFile`).

Answer (score 0):

In terms of reading from the file, I wouldn't recommend this. Hard drives, as far as I know, can't read from more than one place at a single time.

However, processing the data is a different thing entirely, and you can easily do that in multiple threads. (Keeping the data in the correct order also wouldn't / shouldn't be difficult at all.)

Comment: Yes, hdd can't read from multiple places at once, but OS is buffering I/O, so it would be one hdd read for dozens of records.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say very much about what type of processing you intend to do. It is unclear whether you expect the process to be compute- or I/O-bound, whether there are data dependencies between the processing of different rows, etc.

In any case, parallel reading from four vastly different positions in one large file is likely to be inefficient (ultimately, the disk head will have to keep moving back and forth between different areas of the hard drive, with negative consequences for the throughput).

What you might consider instead is reading the file sequentially from start to finish, and fanning out individual rows (or blocks of rows) to the worker threads for processing.